# Android Studio 3.0 - Warning alarmManager may produce NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, warnings, android-studio-3.0

Does anybody face this issue? Why Studio gives a warning?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's Just a warning may produce NPE

Just check not equal like this

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if(alarm != null ) {
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, millis2, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your IDE cannot evaluate if your getSystemService() return a non null value.

You can remove the warning doing :

```
if(alarmManager != null){
    alarmManager.setRepeating(...)
}
```

Comment: are you sure is not there any possibilities?

Comment: You can use the annotation @SuppressWarning